# App is obscuring a permission request settings can't verify your response, can't turn off Overlay

Tags: permissions, webcam

I need to use DroidCam in my phone and PC, it's an app that lets you use your phone cam as a webcam in your PC. Other programs don't work. Since my internet connection is really slow I have to use it via USB. Since my phone screen is mostly not responsive I have installed a pointer type overlay that "draw over other apps".

Because I have that app running, when I try to run DroidCam, it gives me the error message: "Because an app is obscuring a permissions request, Settings cannot verify your response".

But I can't disable my overlay, my mouse pointer, because then I wouldn't be able to use my phone or run that app.

Anyone comes up with a solution?

Comment: If you have connected your phone via USB and have ADB enabled you can control the phone using [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/releases)

Comment: Thank you. This will help me out a lot. Please keep the solutions coming.

Comment: In your device's app settings, there should be a Permissions section.  Can you toggle the permission manually and then start the app?

Comment: Can't Matt because the screen is unresponsive, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (the OP hasn't visited Stack Exchange for more than 2 years and there's no comment/vote on existing answers). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the straightforward options like turning off the ability for other apps to override, but none worked. Finally got around the problem by using the super power saving feature on my tablet that shut off all apps other than those selected. I selected the app I was trying to get the permissions to work for to be the only app running. Opened it, and was finally allowed to enable it without getting this message. Turned off the power saving mode so all other apps were available again, and my new app now seems to be working fine. Would love to know what app was causing the issue but just glad to have it solved.